# Add a suffix to the displayed price of mostly all products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I tried adding `is_product` and `if ( $product->get_id() !== xxx )` to a function but that crashes the function.

Here's the function I am trying to add to all products except one.

```
function change_product_price_html($price){
    if ( $product->get_id() !== 555 ) {
    $newPrice   = $price;
    $newPrice   .= " / m3";
    return $newPrice;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_product_price_html');
```

Do I maybe need an array first to get the product ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the `$product` argument in the function and other mistakes. try instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_product_price_html', 10, 2 );
function change_product_price_html( $price, $product ){
    if ( $product->get_id() !== 555 ) {
        $price .= __(" / m3");
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

For single product pages only using `is_product()` conditional tag:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_product_price_html', 10, 2 );
function change_product_price_html( $price, $product ){
    if ( is_product() && $product->get_id() !== 555 ) {
        $price .= __(" / m3");
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## call $product as global variable. Thats all

```
function change_product_price_html($price){
global $product
if ( $product->ID !== 555 ) {
$newPrice   = $price;
$newPrice   .= " / m3";
return $newPrice;
}
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_product_price_html');
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!